# extraction/isolation of Curcumin from Turmeric using ethanol

Tags: experimental-chemistry, safety

I want to extract/isolate Curcumin from Turmeric using ethanol solvent, already know paramaters such as optimum particulate size, optimum temp (140 degrees F) etc, I need to know how to safely set up a basic distillation to recover the ethanol for reuse.  I have basic lab glassware incl and heat plate/stirrer, condenser.
Thank you

Comment: First off, welcome.  What kind of scale are you talking about (i.e. mg, g, kg of Temeric?).  Could you list the glassware and other relevant lab equipment you have available (flasks and their volumes, vacuum flasks, a roto-vap, etc.).  Have you done this type of thing before, say in an organic chemistry lab or is this your first go?  Actually my last question is by far the most important.

Answer (score 1):

In their open access article *Optimization of the extraction of curcumin from Curcuma longa rhizomes*, published in [*Revista Brasileira de Farmacognosia*, **2013**, *23*, 94-100](http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S0102-695X2012005000117), the authors systematically examined the effect of various parameters on the extraction yield, namely

- drug to solvent weight ratio (1/6 and 1/4 g/g)
- agitation speed (30 and 70 rpm)
- extraction time (12 and 24 h)
- extraction temperature (50 and 80 °C)
- ethanolic strength (70 and 90 % v/v)

Based on their analysis, the following optimum conditions were seemingly predicted:

- drug to solvent weight ratio: 1/6 g/g
- agitation speed: 30 rpm
- extraction time: (12 and 24 h
- extraction temperature: 80 °C
- ethanolic strength: 70% v/v

Please have a look at the full article for further details.

---

**Edit**

> I need to know how to safely set up a basic distillation to recover the ethanol for reuse.

That is a rather fundamental question which suggests that you don't have a lot of experience in organic benchwork.

You might want to have a look at the English wikipedia page on [distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation) for the general setup.

Note that you will not be able to fully separate ethanol and water by destillation. Instead, you will obtain an [azeotrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope), a mixture that has a boiling point lower than that of ethanol and water. In order to check the density of your destillate and to dilute again to an ethanolic strength suitable for extraction, a [hydrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrometer) might be a suitable tool.

In terms of lab safety, the following points should be considered:

- Do not work alone!
- Ethanol vapour is **flammable**!

  1. Keep open flames and electric sparks away.
  2. Run your still in a well-vented place.
  3. Have a fire extinguisher at hand.
  4. Have a work space with an unblocked emergency exit.
- If you use standard lab glassware, a stirrer and an oil bath to heat the still pot, make sure that the tubes for the cooling water that cools your condenser are **properly secured** by wire or clamps. Remember that the heating bath is hot! The last thing that you want is cooling water splashing into the hot silicone oil.

On a lab scale, I would would **not** set up a classical distillation apparatus, but remove (and collect the ethanol) at reduced pressure using a rotary evaporator with a water bath!

- In any case, use suitable **eye protection**!

Comment: I read the question as "How to safely recover the used ethanol?"